# How to add Cc in Amazon SES sendSmtpMail for PHP

Tags: php, amazon-ses

This is the code received from AWS. Unsure on how to add CC dynamically as no input field are existing for the same. Do we need to manage programatically or there are any other ways of managing this.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->setFrom($sender, $senderName);
    $mail->Username   = $usernameSmtp;
    $mail->Password   = $passwordSmtp;
    $mail->Host       = $host;
    $mail->Port       = $port;
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->addCustomHeader('X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET', $headers);
    // Specify the message recipients.
    $mail->addAddress($recipient);
    // You can also add CC, BCC, and additional To recipients here.
    // Specify the content of the message.
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. What input fields are you talking about? And what does this have to do specifically with AWS in the first place, it sounds like it was actually a question about the PHPMailer library. Are you asking how to add CC recipients using that? https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_addCC

Comment: Yes. Need to understand how we can add CC recipients in PHPmailer. We have done it as per the classes defined but still does not work.

Comment: No one can possibly tell what you might have done wrong, if you don’t show us what you actually did in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a link below exactly as follows:

```
$mail->addAddress($recipient);
$mail->addCC($other_recipient);
(optional)$mail->addBCC($recipient_3);
```

Faced the same confusion as you earlier :)